# Multilayer Casting - C++

Tags: c++, casting

## Question

Can a *class type* be **implicitly casted** to a *plain (or POD) type* via *another class type*? *i.e.:*

```
class type -> class type -> plain type (like `int`)
```

---

## Context

So yea, I got **this** challenge. 
I was trying to see if I could **make custom wrappers for POD (or plain) types in C++** as seen in other object-oriented programming languages like **Java** and **JavaScript**

I am **not** trying to build these languages or copy them; 
I am only doing my own practice to see how well I understand C++ (although I *still* mainly use C features).

---

I ended up with this source:

```
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stddef.h>

class Array; class Boolean; class Number; /* Other wrappers */

class Number {
    private:
        long double value;

    public:
        inline Number() : value{0.00} {}
        inline Number(const bool argument) : value{argument ? 1.00 : 0.00} {}
        inline Number(const long double argument) : value{argument} {}
        inline Number(const size_t argument) : value{(long double) argument} {}
        /* Other constructors... */

        inline operator long double() const { return this -> value; } // Can also evaluate to `bool`.
};

class Array {
    public:
        class ArrayLength { // A sort of accessor/ getter class that returns a `Number` type.
            private:
                const Array *array;

            public:
                inline ArrayLength() : array{NULL} {}
                inline ArrayLength(Array *target) : array{target} {}

                operator Number() const { return this -> array -> valueLength; }
        } length;

    private:
        void **value;
        size_t valueLength, valueSize;

    public:
        inline Array() : length{this}, value{NULL}, valueLength{0u}, valueSize{0u} {}

        /* Array methods... */
};

class Boolean {
    private:
        enum {False, True} value;

    public:
        // Still pretty new to copy constructors... heheh.
        Boolean(Array& argument) : value{argument.length ? this -> True : this -> False} {}
        Boolean(Array&& argument) : value{argument.length ? this -> True : this -> False} {}
        Boolean(const Array& argument) : value{argument.length ? this -> True : this -> False} {}
        Boolean(const Array&& argument) : value{argument.length ? this -> True : this -> False} {}
        /* Other constructors... */

        operator bool() const { return this -> value/* == this -> True*/; }
};

int main(void) {
    return 0;
}
```

and came up with this compile-time error:

```
In constructor 'Boolean::Boolean(Array)':
    error: could not convert 'argument.Array::length' from 'Array::ArrayLength' to 'bool'
      Boolean(Array argument) : value{argument.length ? this -> True : this -> False} {}

    error: cannot convert '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'Boolean::<anonymous enum>' in initialization
      Boolean(Array& argument) : value{argument.length ? this -> True : this -> False} {}
```

**8** different **errors** actually, two for each `Array`-based constructor in the `Boolean` class.

---

I already know I could simply manually cast the `Array::ArrayLength` type returned from `argument.length` in the `Boolean` constructor to a `Number` *e.g.:*

```
Boolean(Array& argument) : value{(Number) argument.length ? this -> True : this -> False} {}
```

instead of

```
Boolean(Array& argument) : value{argument.length ? this -> True : this -> False} {}
```

using the `operator Array::ArrayLength::Number() const` method defined in the `Array::ArrayLength` class but that is not the only-use case.

There could be code like this:

```
Array array {};

// Some code...

while (array.length /* Yayy! */) { /* Do something */ }
```

that requires the `array.length` value to be deferred to a `bool` from 
`Array::ArrayLength`.

I'd much prefer if I didn't have to always cast the length of the array to a number when its name  suggests it is already a number.

```
Array array {};

// Some code...

while ((Number) array.length /* Boo... */) { /* Do something else... */ }
```

---

## Possible Solutions

- *Question: "Why not make the `length` member in the `Array` class a `Number` (or inherit from `Number`) in the first place?"*

I would but in this case I want the `length` member to be an accessor/ getter that defaults to a `Number` when called.

Similar to JavaScript when you need an array-like class:

```
class ArrayLike {
    #value = Object.create(null); // Private properties
    #valueLength = 0;

    constructor() { /* Some code */ }

    get length() { return this.valueLength; }
    set length(value) {
        if (typeof value == "number" && Number.isSafeInteger(value)) return (this.valueLength = value);
        else throw new TypeError("Invalid array length");
    }
};
```

- *Question: "Why not allow the `Array::ArrayLength` type be coerced to a `bool` in its definition?"*

Like this?

```
inline Array::ArrayLength::operator bool() const { return this -> array -> valueLength; }
```

I'd like to see if its possible for the design of the code to keep the `Array::ArrayLength` type deferring to a `Number` type for any other type conversions *e.g.:*

```
Array::ArrayLength -> Number -> long double -> bool
```

instead of

```
Array::ArrayLength -> bool
```

---

Cheers

Comment: For implicit conversions the compiler is usually only allowed to do 1. For matching function arguments and converting to bool for example. So the idea to convert `Number -> double -> bool` would mean 2 conversions needed and it's just not gonna work implicitly in many cases.

Comment: It's not really clear to me what the question is here. You have 1 option here, make `Number` convert to a `bool`. Or you can just redesign the whole thing.

Comment: Thanks @super. Edited the question to hopefully make it clearer.

Comment: @super: Already tested direct coercion of the `Number` type to `bool` but that doesn't work. I figured the `long double` coercion it had already would be suitable as an alternative already.

Comment: Not sure what you tried, but if you add an `operator bool()` to `ArrayLenght` that part of the error will go away. Wandbox [example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/MSRVTaek4NUnVw9y).

Comment: Also, with the clarified version of your question, the answer is simply no. Not possible.

Comment: @super: Alright. Kinda sucks for me but I can see why it may be a problem if it was possible.

Comment: Maybe a better option for you here is to convert from `Number` -> `Bool` directly.

Comment: @super: Yea. I was thinking maybe instead of using the `Array::ArrayLength` getter, might as well have the `length` member be of the `Number` type (allowing `Number -> bool` conversions).